# How to hide Cogs/Commands from custom Help command

Tags: python, discord.py

I need to exclude certain Cogs/Commands from being embedded in custom help command, though I cannot figure a way to exclude them from the loop.

Any help is appreciated, **thanks!**

````py
@commands.command(name="help")
    async def help(self, context):
        """
        List all commands from every Cog the bot has loaded.
        """
        prefix = config.BOT_PREFIX
        if not isinstance(prefix, str):
            prefix = prefix[0]
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Help", description="List of available commands:", color=config.success)
        for i in self.bot.cogs:          
            cog = self.bot.get_cog(i.lower())
            if cog != "owner":
              commands = cog.get_commands()
              command_list = [command.name for command in commands]
              command_description = [command.help for command in commands]
              help_text = '\n'.join(f'{prefix}{n} - {h}' for n, h in zip(command_list, command_description))
              embed.add_field(name=i.capitalize(), value=f'```{help_text}```', inline=False)
        await context.send(embed=embed)
````

Comment: Which `cogs` do you want to exclude?

Comment: mostly those that need moderator and/or admin privileges to run. Lets say `owner` and `moderation` cogs

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@has_permissions()` or `@has_role()` decorators on top of your commande, it will only be shown in the default help menu if you pass that check.

If you want to make your own custom command, you can iterate over all your bot or cog commands via `self.get_commands()`. Then for each command you can find `command.checks` that returns a list of all the checks added to your command (has_permissions, has_role, or your custom checks). You can then use those checks (they are a function) to check if the author of the message passes them all

This code sends an embed with all the commands that the author can use

```
    @commands.command()
    def help(self, ctx: Context):
        embed = Embed()

        embed.title = f"Admin commands of  {self.qualified_name}"
        for command in self.get_commands():
            name = command.name
            description = command.description
            passes_check = True
            for check in command.checks:
                if not check(ctx.author):
                    passes_check = False
                    break
            if passes_check:
                embed.add_field(name=name, value=description, inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

References :

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#checks
- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions
- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_role

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [can_run (discord.py docs)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.can_run)

```
go = False
    try:
       await command.can_run(self.context)
       go = True  
    except:
       go = False
```

Implement this into your code and it should be good to go (it worked for me)